# Is there a global variant of .git/info/exclude?

Tags: git

Simply, as the title says - is there a global file variant of .git/info/exclude?

I'd like to add a file pattern to be ignored from git, for every git repository on my host.

Comment: I found this by googling "git global exclude". First hit.

Comment: Yes, awesome, it does!